# How does testing work when working in a forked repo in golang?

Tags: go

Consider a situation where a test is failing in a golang project, say "github.com/originaluser/reponame".

A person who wants to fix the bug forks the repo into github.com/forkeduser/reponame" and then go gets it into his local machine.

The test will fail on his machine even after he fixes the bug if the test file is importing from "github.com/originaluser/reponame" because his changes have not been merged with the original project.

How does testing work in such a scenario?

The only resource I found was a [splice.com blog](https://splice.com/blog/contributing-open-source-git-repositories-go/)

Comment: The blog post you linked explains exactly how to do it. What's your question?

Comment: It didn't understand how adding a remote to the local clone of the fork will fix the import paths in the test files.

Comment: It doesn't change the imports. It doesn't need to because your local clone points to the new repo.

Comment: But the test import will still fetch from the $GOPATH/src/github.com/originaluser/reponame right? Sorry if its something obvious.

Comment: Yes, it will. And at that path will be a working copy from your fork, as per the linked blog post.

Comment: The key point is that the bug fixer should work with a repo cloned to $GOPATH/src/github.com/originaluser/reponame, even if that repo is hosted on github at forkeduser/reponame.

Comment: The key point is that you cannot change the path other than the original repo's path.

Answer (score 0):

Just a short and simple solution it to clone the forked repository into the original repository path.

Step 1: create the path `github.com/originaluser/reponame` inside your gopath.

Step 2: change the working directory to your new folder

Step 3: `git clone github.com/forkeduser/reponame.git`

Step 4: fix the bug

Because now your fix is inside the original path, everything works.